# Mystery in the movie "Julia's Eyes"

Tags: plot-explanation, julias-eyes

In the movie *Los ojos de Julia* or *Julia's Eyes* ... did Isaac commit suicide or was he murdered by the invisible-man?

If murdered, how did the invisible-man write a note in the handwriting of Isaac? Also the calls from Isaac's phone to Sara, how were they made?

If he committed suicide then why suddenly? He was not guilty of the crime. He only went to get the video recording. But the recording will have the invisible-man. So no problem for him.

Can you help to explain if Isaac was murdered or comitted suicide, and why?

Answer (score 2):

ref : [Julia's Eyes Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2017/11/08/Los-ojos-de-Julia-Julias-Eyes-2010-Movie-Plot-Ending-Explained)

Isaac was murdered. As you pointed out rightly, at that moment in time Isaac is worried for Julia and is trying to be as protective as possible so that she doesn't lose her eyesight trying to chase ghosts.

> While the suicide note suggests murder, it was probably planted there
>   by Ángel. Ángel has been systematically removing all of the evidence
>   connecting him with Sara. Isaac was going to get his hands on the
>   surveillance tapes that could incarcerate Ángel. Isaac had no reason
>   to commit suicide because he was not the one in the surveillance
>   tapes. Also, Isaac was found hanging in the exact same way Sara was
>   found. We know Ángel killed Sara. As for the phone records where Isaac
>   has made multiple calls to Sara over the past 6 months. Well, those
>   are real, they were actually having an affair. Isaac loved Julia and
>   didn't kill himself.

Towards the end Lia tells Julia this:
ref : [Julia's Eyes Dialogues](https://subtitle-index.org/subtitle/3811111996956845574115607732/julias.eyes.%5Blos.ojos.de.julia%5D.2010.es.brrip.xvid.ac3-vlis.srt)

> Do you really think Isaac killed himself? He loved you. 
>  He loved
>   Sara more. They didn't want to worry you. 
>  That's why they kept
>   you in the dark. Sara told me. 
>  The monster forced him to write
>   the suicide note.

Lia seems to know a lot in this scene. Even regarding the pictures on the wall or about the keys and that the care taker was actually the invisible man. She's been snooping around on her own finding things. From this it looks like Angel had gotten that note created one way or another. Either by force or by forging.

In summary, Isaac was killed by Angel. The suicide note was forced or forged.
The phone calls were real because Isaac and Sara were actually having an affair.